# Scifi story. Music can be bought in pill form

Tags: story-identification

This was a story about music sold in pills. One could buy any musical composition in a pill and the music will live inside you.

The story must have been written quite a while ago as I have read it about 40 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

This might be [The Futurological Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Futurological_Congress) by Stanislaw Lem.  It was published in 1974 in English, so about 40 years ago.  It includes numerous examples of simulated experiences attained by taking very specific drugs (called "psychem" in the book).

> Composers accept their fees, pay their patrons kickbacks, and to the
>   public that comes to the philharmonium to hear the commissioned work
>   performed they slip a little polysymphonicol contrapuntaline.